Why does "p⊃q" instead of "q⊃p" mean "if p then q"?
The “if-then” sentence is called a conditional and will be symbolized as (p ⊃ q). The part to the left of the horseshoe is called the antecedent (what comes before), and the part to the right of the horseshoe is called the consequent (what comes after). So why does "p⊃q" instead of "q⊃p" mean "if p then q"?

Note that $\supset$ is also used to denote supersets, which could be easily confused with the propositional usage of the "same" symbol. The meaning of the symbol depends on the context.

There is no question in your question (the title doesn't count – the question should be in the body). But anyway the reason it's $p\supset q$ and not $q\supset p$ is that if it were $q\supset p$ then you would be asking why it's $q\supset p$ and not $p\supset q$.

Historical reason only.
Peano in 1895 introduced two twin symbols: the symbol $\text C$ [similar to: $\subset$] meaning "is a consequnece" and a backwards "C" [similar to: $\supset$] meaning "from ... we deduce..."
Thus, $q \ \text C \ p$ means "q is a consequence of p", while $p \supset q$ means "from p we deduce q".
Only the second one survived.
